# How to prevent IntelliJ from generating redundant casts in Java 8 stream expressions?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, java-stream

Often when I type Java 8 stream code in IntelliJ (version 2019.1.3 Community Edition) and use autocompletion IntelliJ generates redundant casts in the resulting code.

An artificial minimal example looks like this:

Type:

```
List<? extends List<? extends Future<?>>> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.stream().map(l -> l.stream().map(f -> f.isD
```

with the cursor placed after the capital `D` of `f.isD`. IntelliJ now suggests to me to complete the `f.isD` to `f.isDone()`. When I accept this and press return the following is generated:

```
list.stream().map(l -> l.stream().map(f -> ((Future) f).isDone()));
```

Why does IntelliJ cast `f` to `Future`? This is redundant which is immediately detected by IntelliJ which now complains (i.e. warns) about the redundant cast.

I searched the web for some setting to turn this off or correct this auto-completion somehow but could not find any solution. Please help, this drives me crazy!

Comment: It’s not only redundant, it’s unnecessarily introducing a *raw type*. To me, it looks more like a bug, which would explain why there is no option to turn it off.

Comment: It really looks like a bug which should be posted to IDEA's YouTrack.

Just a small side note for a particular case — `Future::isDone` can be used in case of simple expression, and autoComplete will work after typing `Future::`

Comment: FWIW: I posted an issue to their bug tracker: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-221376

Comment: Fixed in the latest versions. :)

Comment: @ErkiderLoony Maybe you can add an answer and close this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this was a bug in IntelliJ which has been fixed in the latest releases (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-221376).